# How to fix "Serve static content from a cookieless domain" to increase the speed of Magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, error, redirect, performance, optimization

I had completed my magento website called www.bookslab.in. I want to increase the speed of my website. I had checked my website speed on "tools.pingdom.com" it is coming "4.34s" page load time & Performance grade as: 91. My website speed will increase if i remove this 1 error 
1) Serve static content from a cookieless domain
I am attaching the screenshot of my website speed details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you see the uploaded screenshot @ProxiBlue

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Use a cdn to serve static content (js, css and images)

Option 2:

Setup additional CNAME DNS entries:

js.bookslab.in
css.bookslab.in
images.bookslab.in

or setup a wildcard DNS entry *.bookslab.in

Configure site urls accordingly in admin and set js, css and media urls accordingly ( so dont use {base_url} in the url setups )

`system->configuration->web->secure/unsecure urls`

[image]

so for example you will have `https://js.bookslab.in/js` in the js configuration.

For both options 1 and 2:

Now configure your store cookie domain as www.bookslab.in ( important: you will invalidate all current sessions. All active logged in customers will be logged out and active carts will be dropped )

Clear cache

Explanation:
Cookies will now only be served fir content served from www.bookslab.in

The js, css and images urls ( or cdn served content ) will not have cookies as they are not valid for the confugured cookie domain.

Bonus:
On option 2 you have now also done domain sharding. This will also then allow content to be served parrallel.

Hope that helps

Comment: I only understand the CNAME DNS entries part. can you explain me how to configure this all thing.

Comment: Hi. Sure. On my mobile ( at time of answer and now ) will expand when at office in a couple of hours. Go ahead and configure cnames so dns can start propagation

Comment: @SalmanDalal updated with example

Comment: Do i have to replace the above urls with the urls have stated above as js.bookslab.in & more

Comment: so for example you will have `https://js.bookslab.in/js` in the js configuration.

Comment: Not getting @ProxiBlue

Comment: Sorry. I cannot explain this any clearer. I don't understand how you cannot understand. I suggest you hite a local based developer to help you. Good luck.

Comment: I don't need any local developer who understand me all these. i understood 50% of this  solution but dont know how to follow & how to change the links

Comment: In admin browse to system->configuration->web then edit the web urls as indicated in answer

Comment: Okzz i will check & get back to u

Comment: So, did it work? It is good manners to accept answers and close them off.

Comment: I am checking now by changing the links in the admin panel

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @ProxiBlue, i had researched a lot & i found that when i changed the links in the admin panel then entire website is getting disappeard

Comment: Can you attach an image of what you changed URLs to?

Comment: I did not changed yet i done research only

Comment: "....when i changed the links in the admin panel then entire website is getting disappeard"   so you did make a change, according to your comment. I want to know what URLs you put in. And what does 'site disappeared' mean? Blank screen, some error.... Not very clear.

Comment: I did not changed anything i just searched on google & some people suggested me that if you change the links that u instructed then your website will get disappeared.

Comment: Ok, well, choose to believe them, no worries. Hope it all works out for you.

Comment: just checking. You do realise that teh screenshots provided with the base url of MY SITE, is just that - example. You should substitute YOUR SITE url in the base url. Just in case that is what you are revering to.

Comment: I will check & get back to u

Comment: I had uploaded my Secure & Unsecure URLS of admin panel, so what to do now & is it risky to change this URLS

Comment: @ProxiBlue, how to do same in magento 2?